# Null hypothesis for individual coefficient's p-value in multivariate logistic regression

Tags: hypothesis-testing, logistic, p-value, multivariate-regression

When calculating $p$-values for individual coefficient $a_i$ (for variable $X_i$) in a multivariate logistic regression, is the null hypothesis

1. that all $a$'s are zero?
2. that $a_i$ is zero and others are not constrained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a single coefficient.  Most software conducts a z-test to test of $H_0:\alpha_i =0$ versus $H_A: a_i \neq 0$.

To test $H_0:\forall i, \alpha _i = 0$ versus $H_A: \exists \alpha_i \neq 0$, use something like a deviance goodness of fit test.